# How to vertically align items with different sizes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing a issue of vertically aligning items when a div contains nested child elements, please check: https://codepen.io/akashpen0501/pen/rNaGgXv

***Note, the container has a fixed height of 200px & I want them children to be centered vertically***

**Current result:**

[image: Vertical align CSS]

I want to align all divs vertically center, as
**Required:**

[image: Vertical align flexbox]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:200px;
}

.container div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center<span class="nested child">nested content</span></div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Please advice.

Comment: Did you mean horizontally align to top?

Comment: @VarshaDhadge: No, vertically. You'll notice the center div is pushed up (half) to align with the other divs (left and right)

Comment: `align-items: center` --> `align-items: flex-start` ?

Comment: I recommend this amazing Flexbox guide at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Note, the container has a fixed height of 200px & I want them children to be centered vertically, changing to flex-start gets them to the top of the container. Updated codepen to reflect a fixed hight div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate this using baseline alignment and pseudo element. Change `baseline` with `center` in the below example to see that left/right will stay at the same place.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 1px no-repeat
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  height:calc(50% + 0.25em)
}
.container div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center<span class="nested child">nested content</span></div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

try [`align-items: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) on the container

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: self-start;
  border: 1px solid black;   
}

.container div{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container span{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center<span class="nested child">nested content</span></div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note, the container has a fixed height of 200px & I want them children to be centered vertically, changing to flex-start gets them to the top of the container

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start; // <----- here
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .container div {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .container span {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center<span class="nested child">nested content</span></div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your child components inside a `<div>` and give then class `.children` with following properties, it will keep your content `vertically aligned` and `horizontally` at the same height.

```
.children{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
 }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:200px;
}

.container div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container span {
  display: block;
}

.children{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=children>
    <div>left</div>
    <div>center<span class="nested child">nested content</span></div>
    <div>right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```